# async execution is different from expected

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

in the following snippet

```
    private async void FinishCommandExecute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FinishCommandExecute_1");
        _granularBlobAnalyzer.SaveResult(SampleID, Operator, Comments);
        Console.WriteLine("FinishCommandExecute_2");
        await Task.Run(() => FlushCommandExecute());
        Console.WriteLine("FinishCommandExecute_3");
        State = GBAState.IDLE;
        Console.WriteLine("FinishCommandExecute_4");
    }

    private async void FlushCommandExecute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FlushCommandExecute_1");
        State = GBAState.FLUSHING;
        Console.WriteLine("FlushCommandExecute_2");
        await Task.Run(() => _granularBlobAnalyzer.Flush()); // Task to wrap sync method
        Console.WriteLine("FlushCommandExecute_3");
        State = GBAState.STOPPED;
        Console.WriteLine("FlushCommandExecute_4");
    }
```

I call FinishCommandExecute (it is bound to a button as command),
and I would expect the **finish command** would call the **flush command** and wait for it to finish, but it doesn't wait past the await inside the flush command...and the execution continues

if you look at the comment, I would **expect** the following in the console

- FinishCommandExecute_1
- FinishCommandExecute_2
- FlushCommandExecute_1
- FlushCommandExecute_2
- FlushCommandExecute_3
- FlushCommandExecute_4
- **Finish**CommandExecute_3
- **Finish**CommandExecute_4

while the actual is:

- FinishCommandExecute_1
- FinishCommandExecute_2
- FlushCommandExecute_1
- FlushCommandExecute_2
- **Finish**CommandExecute_3
- **Finish**CommandExecute_4
- FlushCommandExecute_3
- FlushCommandExecute_4

why doesnt async wait for the task run in the second async method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FlushCommandExecute` is an *async void*, so it runs *unobserved*, you can't await\wait for it unless you use some sort of synchronisations mechanism like a `AutoResetEvent` etc or refactor your code to call `async Task` and await that.

```
private async void FlushCommandExecute() => await FlushCommand();

private async void FinishCommandExecute()
{
    ...
    await FlushCommand();
    ...
}

private async Task FlushCommand()
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: So await doesn't wait for async void... that explains it... 
I will rewrite, thanks for the answer

Comment: I implemented as suggested the async Task... and to my surprise it works as expected now. I am a surprised since i don't actually return a task in the new method. any idea why it works? :)

Comment: @buildcomplete if i understand what you are saying, when using the `async` keyword the `Task` is automatically returned by the compiler when calling any `await` in the block